# Query not projecting for oderby?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

How can I add an orderby after the select?

```
//what I have now
string country_list = string.Join(":", ctx.Countries.Select(a => a.CountryName).ToArray());

return country_list;

//what I want to do, but the orderby doesnt see the projections
string country_list = string.Join(":", ctx.Countries.Select(a => a.CountryName).OrderBy(b => b.StateId).ToArray());

return country_list;
```

its the projection with b that isnt working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `OrderBy` before `Select`, because after projection the column you're trying to order by is no longer available:

```
string country_list = string.Join(":", ctx.Countries.OrderBy(b => b.StateId).Select(a => a.CountryName).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.Countries.Select(a => new { a.CountryName, a.StateId })
             .OrderBy(b => b.StateId)
             .ToArray()
```